# Is it possible to use Fastlane on an iOS app with extensions?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym, fastlane-deliver

I am working on adding a Notification Service Extension to the app I'm working on, and I am having trouble reconfiguring my Fastlane setup to work with the extension.

### The problem

I don't know how to properly configure my certificates to allow for the new extension.
The error message is as follows:
`error: No profile for team 'TEAMID' matching 'App Provisioning Profile' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'TEAMID/App Provisioning Profile'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'NotificationModifier' from project 'Yeshivat Torat Shraga')`

### What I've tried

- I tried nuking the certs
- and a lot of googling, but I'm pretty lost

---

### Relevant code and outputs

Here is the Fastlane Summary:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|                             fastlane summary                             |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                              | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                                    | 0           |
| 2    | Switch to ios load_asc_api_key lane                 | 0           |
| 3    | app_store_connect_api_key                           | 0           |
| 4    | Switch to ios prepare_signing lane                  | 0           |
| 5    | create_keychain                                     | 0           |
| 6    | match                                               | 2           |
| 7    | Switch to ios fetch_and_increment_build_number lane | 0           |
| 8    | get_version_number                                  | 0           |
| 9    | latest_testflight_build_number                      | 2           |
| 10   | increment_build_number                              | 5           |
| 11   | Switch to ios build_release lane  <== Crashing lane | 0           |
| 12   | update_code_signing_settings                        | 0           |
|    | gym                                                 | 262         |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

And here is my `build_release` lane:

```
  desc "Build the iOS app for release"
  lane :build_release do |options|
    app_identifier = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier)
    app_profile_name = "match AppStore " + app_identifier
    profile_name = "App Provisioning Profile" # the name of the profile to use for the build
    output_name = "YTS" # specify the name of the .ipa file to generate
    export_method = "app-store" # specify the export method
    compile_bitcode = true # specify whether to enable bitcode
 
    # turn off automatic signing during build so correct code signing identity is guaranteed to be used
    update_code_signing_settings(
      use_automatic_signing: false,
      targets: ["Yeshivat Torat Shraga", "NotificationModifier"], # specify which targets to update code signing settings for
      code_sign_identity: "Apple Distribution", # replace with name of code signing identity if different
      # bundle_identifier: app_identifier,
      profile_name: profile_name,
      build_configurations: ["Release"] # only toggle code signing settings for Release configurations
    )

    settings_to_override = {
      :BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER => "com.appdevname.YTS",
      :PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER => app_profile_name,
      # Use BUILDCACHE override compiler paths to ensure that the correct compiler paths are used.
      :CC => "clang",
      :CPLUSPLUS => "clang++",
      :LD => "clang",
      :LDPLUSPLUS => "clang++",
    }

 
    # build the app
    gym(
      scheme: "Yeshivat Torat Shraga", # replace with name of your project's scheme
      output_name: output_name,
      configuration: "Release",
      xcargs: settings_to_override,
      export_options: {
        method: export_method,
        # provisioningProfiles: {
        #   app_identifier => app_profile_name
        # },
        compileBitcode: compile_bitcode
      }
    )
    end
```

---

I think the root of the issue is that the certs that fastlane is using don't include the Notification Service Extension that I added, but I have no clue where to start fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by removing any references to names of certificates and profiles, and let Fastlane handle the certs by itself. I am still having some issues with entitlements, and I will update this answer if I make progress on this.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20482#issue-1308939683) to the GitHub issue I opened regarding the remaining issue I am facing with certificates.